# How do you call the small numbers close to coauthors in an article?

Tags: publications, terminology, formatting, affiliation

In a scientific paper, how do you call the **small numbers or symbols close to coauthor names** that link to their institutions or e-mail addresses, etc.?

Do you call them *"calls"*....? I don't think *"superindexes"* is the right word here.

What is the standard term for these symbols, in this concrete context?

[image: This is an example of what I mean.]

Answer (score 5):

The document ["How to use the IEEEtran LaTeX class"](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf), by M. Shell, who is the developer of that LaTeX class, calls them *author affiliation symbols* (p. 3, first column).

Nothing fancy.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of a collective noun for the superscript symbols referring to notes. So I think you just call them that: superscript symbols referring to the notes.

Comment: I've seen 'footnote symbol' and 'note reference mark' in various guides over the years. My old AIP Style Guide does not refer specifically to them (oddly enough).

Comment: I've seen them be called "llamadas a notas" (note call) in Spanish, but it seems to be an anglicism from  programming, function call.